# Is it possible for something to travel at supersonic speeds in a tunnel?

Tags: aerodynamics

Is it possible for items to travel at supersonic speeds in a tunnel, as opposed to unconfined spaces?

The particular scenario I had in mind was a bullet train travelling faster than the speed of sound in underground tunnels.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be possible? What should be special about the speed of sound? And: I am sure I could shoot a gun in a tunnel and te bullet would be still faster than the speed of sound... Not quit sure what to make of this question.

Comment: Air resistance is the key factor for practical applications.   It would be easier to travel through a partial vacuum than a tunnel where air pressure increases more than outside cause there's less places it can go.   With a partial vacuum tunnel, traveling at high speed should be even easier.

Comment: If the train is a reasonably good fit in the tunnel, air wouldn't bleed past the train but would be pushed ahead out of the tunnel.   The firearms analogy would then be supersonic internal ballistics, i.e when the bullet is still in the barrel.   A shock wave would develop ahead of the train, which would cause tunnel boom (check the Wikipedia entry), but I'm not sure enough of the effect on the train itself to write this as an answer.   I suspect it wouldn't be good.

Comment: The answer is, of course, "it depends", where the dependency is on the tunnel diameter relative to the train, as well as a bunch of other parameters.

Comment: The answer is "Yes if you have **enough power** (TM)"

Comment: @Carl should I have added "without [vapourizing](https://what-if.xkcd.com/13/) the tunnel or the train" to my question?

Comment: Maybe change the title to: are tunnel based super sonic trains physically possible and add the fluid dynamics tag...

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **Yes it is.**

Just think of all the super sonic wind tunnels (with the small difference of stationary walls).

[image: schlieren-photo]